# Analysis for relationship between ordinal and nominal variables

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, descriptive-statistics

I need to test the relationship between 3 variables. The problem is, one variable is ordinal and the other two are nominal (more precisely, both are from a dichotomous scale). I have already looked for this, but it seems to me that there is no suitable type of analysis. The best way currently seems to me to use a logistic regression, but the ordinal variable does not fit in there.
Do you have any ideas which I can search for or a possible solution?

Comment: Check ordered logit here in this website or in the Agresti’s book Categorical Data Analysis.